# How do you bind jQuery functions to dynamically created controls in C# code-behind

Tags: c#, jquery, dynamic-controls

If I dynamically create a control in code-behind, how would I bind jQuery stuff to that control?

IE (this doesnt work, obviously)
mycontrol.Extend(".animate()");

Thanks!

*** LET ME CLARIFY --- I want to bind these properties to this control FROM THE CODE BEHIND... so

Comment: You could have a script on client-side using live method. It will work with controls create dynamically on the page. See it http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Server-side controls are created and rendered on page load.  Don't need to use the `live()` methods unless something is being changed *after* the DOM is generated.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for WebForms, then controls expose their dynamically created ID with `.ClientID`.  Using that, you could have something like this...

```
var emailId = '#<%= EmailInput.ClientID %>';

$(function() {
    $(emailId) // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out the client-side ID of the control (the ID it gets rendered with).
Depending on what version of ASP.NET you are using this can change.

If you use a DOM inspector you can find this information and then you can use the element as normal.

```
// Check if DOM is ready (eg. everything has been rendered)
$(function() {
   // Do stuff with the elements
   $('#myControlsClientID').animate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one simple way is to assign CSSClass properties to the dynamically created controls and target these classes using jQuery